# Azure AD with prompt=none shows Bad Request when user is logged in into another tenant

Tags: azure, authentication, openid, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have an application that supports seamless login with our Azure AD tenant account via OpenID Connect implicit flow. If user is authorized to access the app providing Azure AD issued evidence - access will be granted automatically, otherwise we show regular application login screen.

Every time when user authentication is required we redirect the user to the Azure AD login page (https://login.microsoftonline.com/xyz) specifying `prompt=none`.

Respecting the [ODIC specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html) such flag should have the following effect.

> The Authorization Server **MUST NOT** display any authentication or
>   consent user interface pages. An error is returned if an End-User is
>   not already authenticated or the Client does not have pre-configured
>   consent for the requested Claims or does not fulfill other conditions
>   for processing the request. The error code will typically be
>   login_required, interaction_required. This can be used as a method to
>   check for existing authentication and/or consent.

It generally works as expected, however, there is a case where Azure AD login page **will show an error screen to the End User** and it happens when **User logged into another Azure AD tenant**.

> User account '...' from identity provider
>   'https://sts.windows.net/.../' does
>   not exist in tenant '...' and cannot access the
>   application '...' in that tenant. The
>   account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.
>   Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory
>   user account.

The questions are:

1. Does not it violate the ODIC specification?
2. How to properly handle such cases in seamless for users fashion? (app is not in charge of what is going on after redirect to Azure AD).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I also agree that this is a violation of the spec, can I offer a workaround?

I believe you can try specifying domain_hint or login_hint parameter as well to help the system determine valid session. Hope it would give you the right answer regardless of which session user is signed in at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a violation of the OIDC spec. We have created a bug.

If the error is only occurring because the STS is selecting the wrong session, you could use login_hint or domain_hint to help the STS select the right session.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is in violation of the spec and defeats the purpose of `prompt=none` since the the application can't keep control of the user experience anymore. [@vibronet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2276747/vibronet) may be able to set the record straight on MS side.

Comment: Appreciate your answer! @vibronet, we are calling for you :)

Comment: Oh, @vibronet is Vittorio Bertocci! Love your articles... Thanks for making the world a better place!